# ggsave alters figure when exporting to pdf

Tags: r, ggplot2, cowplot, ggsave

I've created a complex multi-facet figure using `ggplot`. When I save it using the basic `ggsave` command:

```
ggsave("myplot.pdf", plot = my.plot)
```

The margins of the figure facets and of the labels get changed.

What it looks like in the Rstudio plot preview:

Rstudio preview:
[image: Rstudio preview]

The PDF created by `ggsave` with altered margin thickness:

ggsave export:
[image: ggsave export]

Using the following commands:

```
pdf("myplot.pdf")
print(my.plot)
dev.off()
```

Or using the Rstudio pdf export function or `cowplot`

`save_plot()` is even worse, as now the label font size also gets changed:

pdf() export:
[image: pdf() export]

Is there a more reliable tool to create PDFs? I'd like it to look the same as in Rstudio. Apologies for not posting the entire code as the source dataframe is very complicated, I'll try to create a reproducible example in the meantime.

Comment: welcome to SO. the Rstudio preview is kind of never what you get when saving the plot. Font size is a constant, so the relative size changes depending on your so called device size. In ggsave, you set it with "width" and "height" arguments

Comment: (This said, you should not fine tune your plot based on the RStudio preview pane)